# How to NOT save documents using microsoft.office.interop.word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Just wondering if anyone knows how to not save a document after creation when using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.

Basically i am using mail merge to print off a report from c#, the document get made, values are passed to it no problem and i can then print it without any issues, however, I only need to print the document, I do not need to save a copy on the computer.

Once i have passed all the values to the document, i use the following code to print and close the document:

```
wordDoc.PrintOut();
wordDoc.Close();
wordApp.Application.Quit();
```

However, this prints the document and then the 'Save' dialog pops up, asking where to save the document. I dont want this as clicking cancel produces an error (and requires another unwanted interaction from the user), and i dont need to save the file.

Any ideas?

Using Visual Studio 2012, .NET 4.0, and i have tried using the following files types for the office document: .doc, .dot, .docx, .dotx.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass `SaveChanges` parameter as `wdDoNotSaveChanges` to the `Close` method to skip the saving part.

Have a look at:

[how to close a running instance of Word document? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445831/how-to-close-a-running-instance-of-word-document-c)

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.close%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a very late response to Johns question, but I also needed to close an edited document without having that save dialog displayed.

I found this method worked perfectly for me:

```
// Tells the application not to save changes    
((_Application)wordDoc.Application).Quit(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about suppressing alerts?

```
Word.Application word = new Word.Application();
word.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late but you can try this one.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application { Visible = false };
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName, ReadOnly: true, Visible: true);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions dontSave = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges; 
aDoc.Close(dontSave, null, null);
```