# how to close a running instance of MS Word in C#

Tags: c#, windows, process

I am doing an application in which when I launch a MS Word app,
 a button is created and when the MS Word app is closed the button is removed.
So here is   what I did to associate the MS Word and the button...

```
Word.Application wdApp = new Word.Application();
string oldCaption = wdApp.Application.Caption ;
string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
//set caption to random value
wdApp.Application.Caption = guid;
//make sure app is visible:
wdApp.Visible = true;
//find random value to get process id
int processId = GetProcessIdByWindowTitle(guid);

//reset caption
wdApp.Application.Caption = oldCaption;

//create a dictionary
Dictionary<int, Button> mapping = new Dictionary<int, button>();
//add mapping
mapping.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, Button>(processId, deleteButton));




public static int GetProcessIdByWindowTitle(string AppId)
{
   Process[] P_CESSES = Process.GetProcesses();
   for (int p_count = 0; p_count < P_CESSES.Length; p_count++)
   {
        if (P_CESSES[p_count].MainWindowTitle.Equals(AppId))
        {
                    return P_CESSES[p_count].Id;
        }
   }

    return Int32.MaxValue;
}
```

But I got an error here `mapping.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, Button>(processId, deleteButton));`

I am getting this error:  “No overload method for Add takes 1 argument”... 

What should I do ? 

Is there any oher solution for this ?

Thank you.

**EDIT :**

I have modified my code but I can remove only the last button that I created, when I want to remove the others  I can't... I put breakpoint in order to know the value of the different variables.
But when I create 2 buttons, the count in the mapping.add is always equal to 1... Is it normal ?

here is the code:

```
try
            {

                Word.Application wdApp = new Word.Application();
                string oldCaption = wdApp.Application.Caption;
                string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                //set caption to random value
                wdApp.Application.Caption = guid;
                //make sure app is visible:
                wdApp.Visible = true;
                //find random value to get process id
                int processId = GetProcessIdByWindowTitle(guid);


                //reset caption
                wdApp.Application.Caption = oldCaption;


                if( wdApp.Visible == true)
                {

                    deleteButton = new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Controls.Button();
                    //create a dictionary
                    mapping = new Dictionary<int, Button>();
                    //add mapping
                    mapping.Add(processId, deleteButton);
                    PIC_Barre.Controls.Add(deleteButton);




                    //PIC_Barre.Controls.Add(_button);
                }
                ((Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event)wdApp).Quit += () =>
                {

                // remove the button corresponding to the processid
                     var method = (Action)(() =>
                PIC_Barre.Controls.Remove(mapping[processId]));
                     if (mapping[processId].InvokeRequired)
                     {
                         mapping[processId].Invoke(method);

                     }
                 // remove the key from the dictionary

                };
                Debugger.Break();



            }
            catch
            {

            }
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af6z0wa2.aspx

Comment: I don't know how to answer your actual question, but the error you're getting is pretty self explanatory. There is no overload for Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add that takes only 1 argument!! Rather than passing in a KeyValuePair as one argument, just pass in the key and value in that order as two separate arguments.

Comment: You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445831/how-to-close-a-running-instance-of-word-document-c) for solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
Word._Document document = this.Application.ActiveDocument;
document.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
```

Comment: I need to put an event on the close. When I close the document the button must be removed

Comment: Here, `this` is for what ? A Form ?